# iOS 10 while(YES) never break

Tags: objective-c

I have sample code below.

```
- (void)method1 
{
    breakFlag = NO;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method2) withObject:nil];

    while (YES) {
        if (breakFlag) {
            break;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"End method1");
}

- (void)method2
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        NSLog(@"value of i; %d", i);
    }

    breakFlag = YES;
    NSLog(@"End method2");
}
```

I called method1 from `viewDidAppear` with

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method1) withObject:nil];
```

breakFlag is variable instance.

Why while in method1 never be broken?

Comment: Do you see all of the `NSLog` statements from `method2`?

Comment: Is this some sort of test code? You certainly wouldn't want real code like this.

Comment: Do you have run it in the debugger?

Comment: I has ran it in the release.
Running in the debugger does not happen this issue.

Comment: you should explain what you try to achieve, as there are certainly better ways to do so.

Comment: I know above code is not good. I can use better ways.
But i don't understand it not working.

Comment: I has ran it in the release. Running in the debugger does not happen this issue.

how did you understand this?

Comment: @rmaddy you true. It is test code.
@VladHatko i see output of NSLog(). And tried to insert code to update UI (mainthread) after line  `NSLog(@"End method1")` but not working.

Comment: The compiler optimizes the `if (breakFlag) break;` away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C and Objective-C compilers are not really aware of threading. They are, according to the language standard, perfectly entitled to examine code like your `-method1` and see that nothing in the code of the loop changes `breakFlag` and optimize it by hoisting the check out of the loop. That is, it optimizes your method into:

```
- (void)method1 
{
    breakFlag = NO;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method2) withObject:nil];

    if (!breakFlag) {
        while (YES) {
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"End method1");
}
```

It does need to check `breakFlag` after the call to `-performSelectorInBackground:...` because it can't know that that won't change `breakFlag`. But it doesn't need to check it within the loop.

If you were to declare `breakFlag` with the `volatile` qualifier, that would prevent this optimization. That tells the compiler that something can "spontaneously" (outside of what it can analyze) modify `breakFlag` at any time.

However, that's almost never the correct way to write code. Since you've refused to say what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to advise you on better ways to achieve it. A general recommendation is to suggest that you use proper thread synchronization primitives, like semaphores, mutexes, etc. to have threads interact.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(method2) withObject:nil];
```

Try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self method2];
});
```